# Is there a way to monitor advisory messages through ActiveMQ Web Console UI?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I can see messages in queues but not in topics. I don't find any way to create an ad-hoc non-durable subscriber to try to monitor those messages either. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for such a mechanism in the WebConsole.  You would need to write your own application to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the straight answer!